# Cakephp model with conditions

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Is it possible to make relation in cakephp model with some specific conditions:
eg:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Parent' => array(
        'className' => 'Category', 
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id', 
        'dependent' => true
    )
);
```

I want the above relation on where field `parent_id` is not `0`. Please give some overview on How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put conditions in the relations just like you do with finds.

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Parent' => array(
        'className' => 'Category', 
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id', 
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => array(
            ...
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Its returns an Empty array for other fields... Any way for not showing that array where `conditions` match